how to transform a line chart into a bar chart while using plt.subplots()
I'm having some issues trying to transform 4 charts into a singular figure. I have 2 line charts and 2 bar charts , the problem is that whenever use the subplot method my bar charts turn into line charts.
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)

# Line Graphs:
axs[0,0].plot(df1, linewidth=4)
axs[0,1].plot(df2, linewidth=4)

#Bar Graphs
df3 = df3.T
axs[1,1].plot(df3)

df4 = df4.T
axs[1,1].plot(df4)

i tryed:
axs[1,1].df4.plot.bar()

i also tryed:
value_dict = df4.to_dict()
info_list = []
for key, value in value_dict.items():
    info_list.append(value)

plt.bar(df.index, info_list)

But then my chart became a mix of a line and bars. Is there a way of solving this issue?
State of the charts now:

How my bar charts should look


Are you looking for df4.plot.bar(ax=axs[1,1])?

i guess it's that easy, thank you so much!!
